# Compare two videos in a reasonable time

Tags: python, opencv, video, compare

I have about 20 video files, which i want to compare to find similar videos. In those 20 video files could be two almost identical files but they differ in small details like video length or one of the videos has some more footage of the same thing.

- I took a look at OpenCV which provides a methode to read a video frame by frame. But since i need to compare every frame of video 1 with the whole video 2 it took way too long, considering in need to compare 20 videos with each other.
- My second idea was a bit different. Instead of comparing the video, i extracted the audio and tried to compare only the audio. For the audio compare i looked at audiodiff and pyacoustid, but none of them fitted my request.

Now my question is: Am i missing something on how i easily could solve my problem or is it just not possible to compare two video files in a reasonable time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in locating differences, near duplicates, exact duplicates in videos? What exactly are you focusing on because it's not really clear?

Comment: What is the actual characteristic you are comparing for and where is your code?

Comment: @Eypros i want to find near duplicates. For example: imagine you'd create 2 short clips from the same video. The 2 clips show almost an identical scene but most likely aren't exactly the same.